# R: Standardize using mean and sd functions

Tags: r, transform, mean, standard-deviation, standardized

I'm trying to do a simple transformation. I've used the following code and it worked fine:

```
data_stdz <- transform(data_header, z.v1 = v1+2)
```

But, I can't get the following code to work:

```
data_stdz <- transform(data_header, z.v1 = (v1 - mean(v1))/(2*sd(v1))
```

I've also tried to get just the mean function to work:

```
data_stdz <- transform(data_header, z.v1 = mean(v1)
```

But, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"data_std2 <- transform(data_header, z.v1 = mean(v1)
data_std2"
```

So I'm guessing it has something to do with how I am using the mean and sd function, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Data example:

```
v1   v2  v3
6.7 3.8 1.2
6.3 3.2 1.2
6.1 2.6 1.6
7   2.4 1
NA  NA  NA
6.5 3.6 2.6
6.1 2.4 1.6
6   5.6 5.2
7   2.8 1
6.7 3.8 1.4
5.7 4.2 2.6
5.1 5.6 5
NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: That error doesn't immediately scream `mean()` or `sd()` to me. You have missing closing parentheses in both the `transform()` calls. It looks like that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the parentheses Gavin!

Comment: Also worth looking at the `scale` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely (in additon to what gavin said) the NAs.  Use `na.rm=TRUE` as in:

```
transform(data_header, z.v1 = (v1 - mean(v1, na.rm =T))/(2*sd(v1, na.rm =T)))
```

Comment: Take a look at Dirk's suggestion too.  It may be a better approach to what you're attempting.  And Tom when you're having trouble with a function (not sure how new you are to R) using ?function.name as in `?mean` gives you a nice help file on the function including arguments.  In many instances it's improper argument specification that leads to errors.

Comment: Very new to R, but not new to seeing double parentheses. Thanks for the advice as I looked for information on the mean function and it was not helpful, but the ?mean is.

Answer (score 2):

Base R has the `scale()` function for this purpose.

Comment: While my answer answers the  poster's immediate problems Dirks is a much better approach to what you're attempting to do.  `scale` has lots of other arguments that make this a very handy for many different tasks.

Comment: I did consider the scale () function but wasn't sure how to calculate 2*sd using it.